# <ui:outputText /> to display "Guest" if no user is Logged in?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, customer-portal, aura

Below is what I have implemented:

```
 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.user != NULL}">
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.user.Name}"/> 
    <aura:set attribute="else">
    <ui:outputText value="Guest"/>
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

I am trying to display text **Guest** if I am accessing the Community URL without any login user (say using Chrome's Incognito window). 
What I am getting to display is: **Customer Portal Site Guest User**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that `NULL` is case sensitive.

Try this:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.user != null}">
```

And it looks like the user is never null. If the user has not logged in, then they are a **Customer Portal Site Guest User**. If they have, they will get some other name. You should probably make your test something like:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.user != null, v.user.Name != 'Customer Portal Site Guest User')}">
```

Comment: It seemed working, BUT just for half a second and refreshing to **Customer Portal Site Guest User** again. Am I am still missing something to include?

Comment: I'm guessing that before you query completed, the user WAS null. Then, it had a value. Your user really is the **Customer Portal Site Guest User**. Your logic is ok, now you need to figure out why you are getting the guest user. Look at your controller, try debugging your Apex and JS code.

Comment: My JScontroller contains basic **doInit** function and Apex controller has a query to fetch the logged in user by **Id == UserInfo.getUserId()**. I am clueless at this point. Could you please tell me the ways I can debug?

Comment: Updated my answer - see if this works

Comment: @ArnoldJr. UserInfo.getUserId() never returns null. There is a "guest user" account created for each community, so you'll need to check to see if the logged in user is a guest user. This is true for all communities, portals, and so on.

Comment: @sfdcfox That works. Man, you are just awesome. The best man on the Salesforce Stack Exchange. \m/

Thank you Caspar for your answer.